# Consulta SqlServer en html

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, conexión

Estoy haciendo una página web con html y css. Necesito que haga una consulta en una base de datos SQLServer, estoy intentando hacerlo con php pero no he conseguido tener exito, por el momento tengo lo siguiente. Primero intento hacer una conexión en un archivo tipo php al que llame conexion

```
<?php
 $user="CC_ALMConsulta_Mon";
 $pass="XXX";
 $servidor="SRVXXX297";
 $bd="DB_Servers";

 $con=sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $user,$pass,$bd);

 if (!$con) {
   die("Error al conectar".sqlsrv_connect_error());
 }?>
```

Desúpes en el archivo html mando llamar la pagina de php y hago la consulta y lo acomodo en una tabla, pero no detecta que es codigo php dentro del html.
Esto es lo que tengo en body

```
<body>

 <?php
   include("conexion.php");
   $OBM_VIEW="";

   $consulta="SELECT [OBM_VIEW]
     ,[VIEW_DATETIME]
     ,[CMDBID_OP]
     ,[CITYPE_OP]
     ,[CINAME_OP]
     ,[CIDESC_OP]
     ,[CIDSLB_OP]
     ,[CMDBID_MP]
     ,[CITYPE_MP]
     ,[CINAME_MP]
     ,[CIDESC_MP]
     ,[CIDSLB_MP]
     ,[CMDBID_PR]
     ,[CITYPE_PR]
     ,[CINAME_PR]
     ,[CIDESC_PR]
     ,[CIDSLB_PR]
     ,[CMDBID_BS]
     ,[CITYPE_BS]
     ,[CINAME_BS]
     ,[CIDESC_BS]
     ,[CIDSLB_BS]
     ,[CMDBID_IS]
     ,[CITYPE_IS]
     ,[CINAME_IS]
     ,[CIDESC_IS]
     ,[CIDSLB_IS]
     ,[CMDBID_CI]
     ,[CITYPE_CI]
     ,[CINAME_CI]
     ,[CIDESC_CI]
     ,[CIDSLB_CI]
     ,[CMDBID_CI2]
     ,[CITYPE_CI2]
     ,[CINAME_CI2]
     ,[CIDESC_CI2]
     ,[CIDSLB_CI2]
     ,[AV_GREEN]
     ,[AV_ORANGE]
     ,[AV_YELLOW]
     ,[AV_RED]
     ,[PF_GREEN]
     ,[PF_ORANGE]
     ,[PF_YELLOW]
     ,[PF_RED]
     ,[LS_GREEN]
     ,[LS_ORANGE]
     ,[LS_YELLOW]
     ,[LS_RED]
 FROM [DB_Servers].[dbo].[mabe_CC_OBM_Ind_VW]
 WHERE OBM_VIEW=upper('ZMMabe_SAL [Mabe Saltillo Macroprocesses]')";

   if (!$resulatado=sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta)) {
     die("Error:  ".sqlsrv_connect_error());
   }else{
     "Conexion exitosa  "
   }


   echo '<table border="2px solid">';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th>'."OBM_VIEW".'</td>';
   echo '</tr>';

   while ($fila=sqlsrv_fetch_row($resulatado)) {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$OBM_VIEW=$fila[0].'</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
   }
       echo '</table>';


  ?>
</body>
```

Existe alguna manera de que mi codigo funcione o lo tengo que hacer con otro lenguaje?

Comment: "pero no detecta que es codigo php dentro del html." Si no lo detecta, es porque tu servidor de php o está apagado o no lo estás usando.

Comment: No lo estoy usando, ¿me puedes recomendar alguno?

Comment: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) , puedes encontrar documentación, tutoriales de uso, etc

Comment: muchas gracias, ya logre realizar la conexión, ya solo voy a intentar hacer la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de los problemas de infraestructura, que parece ya has resuelto, convendría que ahora te centres en la calidad de tu código.

Veo varios errores y prácticas que se pueden mejorar.

- Nunca pongas salida por pantalla en archivos que podrías utilizar en varios contextos, como es tu conexión. Por ejemplo, en un caso donde necesites **una respuesta estructurada** como un JSON o un XML, esa salida va a romper esa estructura en caso de que no haya conexión. Debes controlar el estado de la conexión en cada contexto.
- En ese código la variable `$OBM_VIEW="";` no tiene ninguna utilidad, porque los datos se van a imprimir *in situ*. Ella está ahí ocupando memoria, nada más.
- Verifica la *ortografía* en la declaración de tus variables. No es grave, pero es incómodo y puede llevar a errores futuros. Me refiero a `$resulatado`, creo que debería ser `$resultado`. Y, si adoptas una convención de nombre en inglés, mejor que mejor.
- Hay líneas de tu código que no terminan por `;`.
- En producción, no conviene mostrar mensajes internos tales como `sqlsrv_connect_error()`. Podrían revelar información que usuarios mal intencionados podrían explotar para atacar tu servidor. La mejor práctica es poner mensajes personalizados.
- Tu elemento HTML `table` no se está construyendo correctamente. Estás abriendo un `th` y lo cierras con un `td`. Además, las concatenaciones son abusivas en ese punto. En vez de: `echo '<th>'."OBM_VIEW".'</td>';` puedes hacer simplemente: `echo '<th>OBM_VIEW</th>';`

Aplicando todo lo dicho, yo escribiría el código así:

### Conexión

Totalmente libre de salidas por pantalla.

```
<?php

 $user="CC_ALMConsulta_Mon";
 $pass="XXX";
 $servidor="SRVXXX297";
 $bd="DB_Servers";
 $con=sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $user,$pass,$bd);

?>
```

#### Contexto

Vamos a controlar el flujo en una variable. Y mostraremos esa variable al final, sea con la tabla, sea con un mensaje de error.

```
<body>
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    if ($con) {
        $consulta="SELECT [OBM_VIEW]
            ,[VIEW_DATETIME]
            ,[CMDBID_OP]
            ,[CITYPE_OP]
            ,[CINAME_OP]
            ,[CIDESC_OP]
            ,[CIDSLB_OP]
            ,[CMDBID_MP]
            ,[CITYPE_MP]
            ,[CINAME_MP]
            ,[CIDESC_MP]
            ,[CIDSLB_MP]
            ,[CMDBID_PR]
            ,[CITYPE_PR]
            ,[CINAME_PR]
            ,[CIDESC_PR]
            ,[CIDSLB_PR]
            ,[CMDBID_BS]
            ,[CITYPE_BS]
            ,[CINAME_BS]
            ,[CIDESC_BS]
            ,[CIDSLB_BS]
            ,[CMDBID_IS]
            ,[CITYPE_IS]
            ,[CINAME_IS]
            ,[CIDESC_IS]
            ,[CIDSLB_IS]
            ,[CMDBID_CI]
            ,[CITYPE_CI]
            ,[CINAME_CI]
            ,[CIDESC_CI]
            ,[CIDSLB_CI]
            ,[CMDBID_CI2]
            ,[CITYPE_CI2]
            ,[CINAME_CI2]
            ,[CIDESC_CI2]
            ,[CIDSLB_CI2]
            ,[AV_GREEN]
            ,[AV_ORANGE]
            ,[AV_YELLOW]
            ,[AV_RED]
            ,[PF_GREEN]
            ,[PF_ORANGE]
            ,[PF_YELLOW]
            ,[PF_RED]
            ,[LS_GREEN]
            ,[LS_ORANGE]
            ,[LS_YELLOW]
            ,[LS_RED]
        FROM [DB_Servers].[dbo].[mabe_CC_OBM_Ind_VW]
        WHERE OBM_VIEW=upper('ZMMabe_SAL [Mabe Saltillo Macroprocesses]')";
        
        if ($resultado=sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta)) {
            $outPut='<table border="2px solid">';
            $outPut.='<tr><th>OBM_VIEW</th></tr>';
            while ($fila=sqlsrv_fetch_row($resultado)) {
                $outPut.=sprintf("<tr><td>%s</td></tr>",$fila[0]);
            }
            $outPut.='</table>';
        } else {
            $outPut='No se encontraron datos';
        }
    } else {
        $outPut='Error en la conexión';
    }
    die($outPut);
?>
</body>
```

Comment: ¡Hola! Muchas gracias, tiene años que no manejo programacion para paginas web, voy a intentar aplicar todo lo que me recomiendas, en el resultado del if como podria poner de color el resultado (th) en caso de no estar vacio?   <?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :  ?>
 <tr>
   <th scope="row">  <?php if( $fila->AV_GREEN!="0"){
       echo "Campos llenos";
     }else {
             echo "Campos vacios";
     } ?></th><?php endforeach; ?>